# Chrome Extension: Access-Control-Allow-Origin in background script and content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cors

Please explain to me the difference in CORS for background script and content script.

When I make a fetch request from the content script, the headers are:

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
origin: http://example.org
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: **cross-site**
```

and I get the error Access to fetch at 'https://api.blah-blah-blah' from origin 'http://example.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

And when I make the same request from the background script, everything is fine, the headers are:

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
origin: chrome-extension://faebbackmmlgdbgjmljofnijfdfaepbo
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: **none**
```

and I get the correct responce.

Are http://example.org and chrome-extension the same origin?

Comment: They are different origins. [http://example.org](http://example.org) is the origin of the page that injected the content script.

Comment: When you have the site covered by your extension's host permissions the request made from an extension page or background script goes in same-origin mode. The content script uses the origin of the web page, no special handling, which is why it retains cross-origin mode.